# Can twemproxy load balance read requests?

Tags: redis, load-balancing, redis-sentinel, twemproxy

I want to use redis with master and slaves. 
I.e. several shards. Each shard has one master and several slaves.

Is it possible to configure twemproxy to use masters to write and slaves to read? Or all requests will go to the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is just able to distribute keys with various methods. It does not support read slaves. You could build sth. like that with haproxy easily though.